# Unable to connect to remote SMTP server

Tags: php, smtp

When i use this script to connect to SMTP server on same domain it works but when i use it for remote SMTP it gives error

```
$mail->IsSMTP();                                // send via SMTP
$mail->Host     = "xxx.xxx.x"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "xxxxt@xxxxx.com";   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxxxx"; // SMTP password
$mail->Port = 26; 

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->From     = "email@domain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Name";
$mail->AddAddress("xxxx.oxxk@gmail.com");
//$mail->AddReplyTo("yourname@domain.com","Your Name");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                              // set word wrap

$mail->IsHTML(true);                               // send as HTML

$mail->Subject  =  "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body     =  "This is the <b>HTML body</b>";
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message was not sent <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
```

echo "Message has been sent";

ERROR generated:

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message was not sent

Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Can anyone plz point out what i have missed.

Thanks

Comment: "Connection refused" is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: Is the remote host running a SMTP server? Does it accept connections on the correct port? No firewall blocking?

Comment: Coudnt connect to host clearly shows that you have doing some mistake in connecting to host (i.e. `host ip` , `username` , `password`) also note SMTP default port is `25` ..

Comment: the remote server does run SMTP server ..if i run this script at remote server it works..how can i find if there is a firewall blocking

Comment: @shazia best ask the company that is running the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

1st are you running this script on your local computer like wamp or xammp server's .. if yes than you need to download a free smtp server you can try postcast server it works with windows... and then make some changes in php.ini file

http://www.postcast.com/html/download.asp ( download it from here )

Changes for php.ini file

1. SMTP = localhost
2. smtp_port = 25
   sendmail_from = someid@somemail.com   // this will the defualt address used to send mail you can even put your gmail id

Comment: i have uploaded the script onto host which has an SMTP server. I have used port 25 and even tried 26